# Why Testing Result and ASR output after deploy is different in Microsoft Custom Speech?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am training ASR using Microsoft Custom Speech, and I found that when I test the model throught Testing tab, output ASR is correctly recognized, but after deploy to endpoint and test using Check endpoint using same input audio file, recognized ASR is different.

Anyone has idea what make two result different? and how I can fix it?
Basically same input file and same model but ASR reult is different according to Testing, or Deployment->check endpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible could you please share side-by-side comparison results.

Comment: Also please share the input audio file and output results to check.